Shopify Hydrogen - Issue with Blog->Article retrieve via GraphQL - UNAUTHORIZED?
This was working fine for days until I noticed it not working today. I was pulling articles from a blog via GraphQL. Today, I saw a:
Oops
500 [h2:error:storefront.query] [object Object] - Request ID: 3c8bc60f-d909-4821-89e7-6fd796495c13-1712578684

Digging in via GraphiQL I see the object return:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "",
      "extensions": {
        "code": "UNAUTHORIZED"
      }
    }
  ]
}

All articles do this. Nothing has changed in the shopify admin area. Articles are 'visible'. My non-headless site shows the article fine. The primary blog 'collection' shows the articles and assets associated with it as well. I get the error when trying to access the article directly. Any ideas?
Here is the GraphQL that is run
query Article($articleHandle: String!, $blogHandle: String!, $country: CountryCode, $language: LanguageCode) @inContext(language: $language, country: $country) {
  blog(handle: $blogHandle) {
    articleByHandle(handle: $articleHandle) {
      title
      contentHtml
      publishedAt
      author: authorV2 {
        name
      }
      image {
        id
        altText
        url
        width
        height
      }
      seo {
        description
        title
      }
    }
  }
}

Again, this has been working and I haven't been in this code for a bit.

It does not matter that is was working, the question is more, why is it not? Assume a glitch at Shopify. Not much you can do but wait it out.

Thanks. Not sure what it's up, but you're right, it's working now.
